# Using sAMAccountName as uid in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, architecture, ldap

I have an application that authenticate with `LDAP` and returns a `JWT` with the `sAMAccountname` of the logged user.

This application have a `MySQL` database where I'd like to store the user in different tables *(fields like createdBy, updatedBy, etc.)* and I was wondering what is the correct way of handling this:

- using the sAMAccount name as identifier (so the createdBy will be a `VARCHAR(25)`)
- using a link table to match the sAMAccountname with an autoincremented identifier

Normally I would choose the "id" way, it's faster and easier to read in my opinion, but I'm not really into linking users from LDAP dictionary and changing their id in my database, so honestly I would choose the first option.

What are the pro/cons of using a string as `uid` ? In my case it's likely to be only for statuses like `updatedBy`, `cratedBy`, `deletedBy` etc. so I won't have hardlinks between multiple tables using an user identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create user table with a surrogate primary key (autoincrementing one) and make unique index on sAMAccount column.

Natural primary keys are good because they just naturally describe a record they point to. But the downsize of using them is that they consume too much space in the index. Index lookups / rebuilds are slower. Tables consume more space also.

Comment: that was my concern too, using varchar as index isn't just good generally

Comment: @kitensei Yep. So choose wisely ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd connect everything using an id as primary key.

ONe thing is that the `sAMAccountName` is not necessarilly unique. Think of a user changing her or his name. The `sAMAccountName` might then change but it's still the same user. When you connect everything via an ID you can change the `sAMAccountName`-field without breaking everything.

But that's just my 2 cent

Comment: Yeah I can see the problem but in my society sAMAccountName won't change, too many links, I'll accept FractalizeR's answer as it was the first one, but thank you for your precisions

Comment: As we bith suggested the same (just for different reasons) thats fair enough :)